# How to get Route URL param in Controller | Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have the following route:

```
Route::get('/category/{category}/keyword/{keyword}', 'CategoryController@search');
```

In my controller I am trying to retrieve both the URL params using the following code:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $request->all();
    ...
}
```

The above code doesn't return the value of parameters.

If I call the following code, I get the value:

```
$request->category
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. `$request->all()` will return an array of form-data (POST)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 public function search($category, $keyword)
```

or this:

```
 public function search(Request $request, $category, $keyword)
```

If you need the Request object.

The route parameters are injected in the funcion call, they are not in the request inputs.

Comment: I think anything dependancy injected (like the Request) has to be after any segment variables. `public function search($category, $keyword, Request $request)`

Comment: For me its working with injected Request in first position

Comment: Also the laravel docs put the injected Request in first position with route parameters, see here at the paragraph "Dependency Injection & Route Parameters": https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests